# Replace with backslash

Tags: java, regex

So when I run the following,

```
String thing = "y$xx$sss$$aaa";                         
thing = thing.replaceAll("$", "\\$");                           
System.out.println(thing);
```

I still get `"y$xx$sss$$aaa"` as the output. I've also tried

```
String thing = "y$xx$sss$$aaa";                         
thing = thing.replaceAll("$", "\\\\$");                         
System.out.println(thing);
```

and

```
String thing = "y$xx$sss$$aaa";                         
thing = thing.replaceAll("$", "\\\\\\\\$");                         
System.out.println(thing);
```

per some existing answers, but I just kept getting the error `Illegal group reference: group index is missing`.

Basically, I'm trying to replace all `$` with an escaped dollar sign `\$`

Comment: @wiktorstribizew Hasn't he done just what the linked duplicate answer is saying? Apparently it's not working.

Comment: Or [`.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$")`](https://ideone.com/HXK6UO).

Comment: @Gendarme it appears that OP has done that yes. I'm wondering if the $ needs to also be escaped, a la 3 backslashes? OP, have you tried "\\\$"?

Comment: @Gendarme: No, in the linked answer, a `replace` is used. Not `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there:

```
thing = thing.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$");
```

You need to escape the first `$`, otherwise it's a regex command character signifying end of input.

The second arguments requires a lot of escaping too:

- 1st double-escape to avoid replacing with literal `$`
- 2nd and 3rd double escape to prevent referencing a group number (the escaped `$` character) and add an actual back-slash

Then again, **easier solution without regular expressions**:

```
thing = thing.replace("$", "\\$");
```

Note: the latter example does still use `Pattern`s, but it quotes the arguments as literals internally.